# Is there any feature of TextBlob to obtain neutral classification?

Tags: python, text-mining, textblob

I am interested in building a text classifier using textBlob but from my research does not look like after you train the classifier to return neutral tags. Does anyone know a way to implement this ? Or is there a similar library which provides neutral classification ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using If else Statement for this : 
like

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from textblob.sentiments import NaiveBayesAnalyzer

blob = TextBlob(message, analyzer=NaiveBayesAnalyzer())
a = (blob.sentiment)
if a.__getattribute__("p_pos") > a.__getattribute__("p_neg"):
    tag = str(a.__getattribute__("classification"))
    sentiment = str(a.__getattribute__("p_pos"))
elif a.__getattribute__("p_pos") < a.__getattribute__("p_neg"):
    tag = str(a.__getattribute__("classification"))
    sentiment = str(a.__getattribute__("p_neg"))
else:
    tag = "N"
    sentiment = "0"
```

If their is neutral sentence, p_pos and p_neg will be equal!

This works for me!!!
Hope it works for you

Comment: This returns negative to almost all neutral sentences.
try this message "I am planning to move to New York", "Let's do it"